# cx_freeze gives input and file errors

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, cx-freeze

I've seen similar problems on different forums, but none applies to this.

I have two files, one 'main.py' and the main program 'xlsKonverter.py' which I want to use cx_freeze to compile to an .exe file. When building the .exe I get this error message:

```
pywintypes.error: (110, 'EndUpdateResource', 'The system cannot open the device or file specified.')
```

And when trying to run the (somewhat finished) build, this Exception pops up:

[image]

I've tested all of my code, so the error is not there. It must be somewhere within the setup file. Am I wrong? And what would be a good fix?

---

'setup.py'

This is my cx_freeze setup

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

packages = ['xlrd', 'glob', 'sys']
includes = ['xlsKonverter']
includefiles = []

eggsacutibull = Executable(
    script = "main.py",
    base = 'Console',
    initScript = None,
    targetName = "main.py",
    compress = True,
    copyDependentFiles = True,
    appendScriptToExe = False,
    appendScriptToLibrary = False,
    icon = None
    )

setup(  name = "Table Converter",
        version = "0.3",
        author = "Jørgen Sirhaug",
        description = "Makes a .csv file from designated Wire List.",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [eggsacutibull]
        )
```

'main.py'

, my main function

```
import xlsKonverter as xk
import os.path
import sys

def main():

fileList = xk.getAllFileURLsInDirectory("C:\\Users\\Jørgen\\Dropbox\\Aker\\Wire Lists\\")
if len(fileList) < 1:
    print("ERROR! No files in directory!\nDoes the specified folder excist?")
else:
    print('')
    for i in range(len(fileList)):
        try:
            sheet = xk.getWorksheet(fileList[i])
            tagCols = xk.automaticFirstRow(sheet)
            pairedList = xk.pairCells(sheet, tagCols)
            csvString = xk.makecsv(pairedList)#, tagCols)
            xk.writeToFile(csvString, i)
        except:
            print("ERROR!\n" + fileList[i] + '\nThis file does not excist!')

main()
```

and the imports from 'xlsKonverter.py'

```
import xlrd
import glob
import sys
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting an encoding declaration in your main.py file. That's a comment that looks like this:

```
# encoding: cp1252
```

You might have to change the last bit depending on how you're saving the file. If it's created on Windows, cp1252 is normal for Western Europe. On Linux and Mac, `utf8` is more common.

Comment: I have `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as the first line in my main. Is there any difference in writing `#-'- coding` and `# encoding`?

Comment: That should work. What happens if you do `tokenize.detect_encoding(open("main.py", "rb").readline)` ?

Comment: Also, does `open('main.py', 'rb').read().decode('utf-8')` raise an error?

Comment: `tokenize`? It's not a function I've heard of.
And no, neither of them worked. `tokenize` does not excist, and `open()` just gives a 404 error.

Comment: tokenize is a module, you need to import it before you use it. And a 404 error - what? Where are you trying this? 404 is an HTTP error code, that's completely unrelated to opening a file in Python.